# SciChart AutoRange not working properly for small values

Tags: android, scichart

I found out that AutoRange on Y axis is not working properly when chart values are very small. See an example:

Working well (normal values):

[image]

Not working well (small values):

[image]

I am actually able to tap a few times to zoom it in, here is the max extent:

[image]

As you can see

- AutoRange is not applied automatically
- I can not zoom in to fill whole Y range
- MACD indicator chart has the same problem

I construct Y axis like this when I make a model:

```
            this.yAxis = builder.newNumericAxis()
                    .withAxisId(PRICES)
                    .withAutoRangeMode(AutoRange.Once)
//                    .withDrawMinorGridLines(true)
//                    .withDrawMajorGridLines(true)
//                    .withMinorsPerMajor(4)
//                    .withMaxAutoTicks(8)
//                    .withGrowBy(new DoubleRange(0.000001d, 0.000001d))
                    .withLabelProvider(new NumericLabelProviderPrice(currency))
                    .build();
```

Experimenting with different `withGrowBy` params produced limited results.

---

How do I make Y AutoRange to work automatically no matter if chart values are big (>1000) or small (<0.01)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to set [MinimalZoomConstrain](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/webframe.html#Axis%20Ranging%20-%20Restricting%20VisibleRange.html) = 0?

```
yAxis.setMinimalZoomConstrain(0d);
```

This should disable any constraints of zoom depth.

By default NumericAxisBuilder sets it to 0.01 to prevent very deep zoom of chart and if VisibleRange does not satisfy MinimalZoomConstrain then axis resets it to default value which is equal to (0, 10) in case of NumericAxis.